# Sitecore Aggregation in Preview Mode

Tags: sitecore, aggregation, preview

I want to ask, is sitecore aggregation feature working for preview mode page? Because if i tried, the aggregation doesn't work if in preview mode. Or is there any configuration to enable it?
Btw i'm using Sitecore 8.2
Thank you.

Comment: add code sample in your question to help people to help you.

Comment: better to ask this question on - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/